# How can I format currency by using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, currency

I am trying to format currency by using this code below:

```
$('#currency').keyup(function(e){
   var val = $(this).val();
   val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
   if(val.length >= 2)
   val = '$' + val.substring(0,2) + ',' + val.substring(2);
   if(val.length >= 6)
   val = val.substring(0,7) + val.substring(7);
   if(val.length > 7)
   val = val.substring(0,7); 
   $(this).val(val);
 });
```

But that would work only for volume such as "$10,000" or something like that, How can I include thousands, hundreds, and millions in one code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a nice function in vanilla JS that handles things:

```
var format = function(num){
    var str = num.toString().replace("$", ""), parts = false, output = [], i = 1, formatted = null;
    if(str.indexOf(".") > 0) {
        parts = str.split(".");
        str = parts[0];
    }
    str = str.split("").reverse();
    for(var j = 0, len = str.length; j < len; j++) {
        if(str[j] != ",") {
            output.push(str[j]);
            if(i%3 == 0 && j < (len - 1)) {
                output.push(",");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    formatted = output.reverse().join("");
    return("$" + formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : ""));
};
```

However, for jQuery, you could always turn it into a plug-in, or just use it like:

```
$(function(){
    $("#currency").keyup(function(e){
        $(this).val(format($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
I updated the fiddle
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6rCN/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your response @faino, I am not a fan of a plug-in.. i just want to include jquery in the file not using any plug-in.. 
If I will use this code that you provided:
$('#currency').keyup(function(e){
    $(this).val(format($(this).val()));
});
Do I have to include plug-in?

Comment: No you don't, I did some modifications to the original script and if you take a look at the updated fiddle, you'll see what it's doing.

Comment: @Swanney_14 if this did helped you can kindly accept/upvote this answer

Comment: I would definitely do that!

Comment: there is a small issue (which can be fixed easily) with this code, try using ***Left Arrow*** key, you see it can't move to the digit you want it to move to.

Comment: after trying numerous Javasript and Jquery plugins online, this is the first I found that actually worked!  I had to wrap it in an if statement to only allow numbers and decimals, but that was easy.

Comment: @dmikester1 - did you want to share how you did this for others?

Comment: That was a while ago, took me a bit to find it.  Here was the code I used: `if (isNumberKey(e) && !e.shiftKey) {
                    $(this).val(format($(this).val()));
                }`

Comment: I changed the return line in order to show hint text when all input was removed. It could be better but it gets the job done.

`var result = "$" + formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : "");
    
    if (result == "$") {
        result = "";
    }
    
    return result;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` in solving this problem, note that your input field should prevent user from typing letter/non-digit character, other than replacing all the typed non-digit characters with empty string, doing that is not professional:

```
$('input').on('input', function(e){    
  $(this).val(formatCurrency(this.value.replace(/[,$]/g,'')));
}).on('keypress',function(e){
  if(!$.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) e.preventDefault();
}).on('paste', function(e){    
  var cb = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;      
  if(!$.isNumeric(cb.getData('text'))) e.preventDefault();
});
function formatCurrency(number){
  var n = number.split('').reverse().join("");
  var n2 = n.replace(/\d\d\d(?!$)/g, "$&,");    
  return "$" + n2.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/V2mg6/3/)

Comment: Thanks you for your response, really close what I am looking for! The only thing I want to include it in input when client typing the number, it would change in the input itself..

Comment: @Swanney_14 what do you mean? in fact the problem of preventing user from typing non-digit character is another problem, the problem of converting number to currency format is another one. They are totally 2 separate steps of formating your data.

Comment: @Swanney_14 I know you accepted the best answer however I just updated my answer, you should mention your exact requirement before asking some question next time.

Comment: Yes, Thank you.. I am sorry for being not specific in my question.. That is was I was looking for Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jquery plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>JQuery FormatCurrency Sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.formatCurrency.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, div  { margin:0px auto; padding:0px; }

            .main { margin:40px; }

            .sample { float:left; margin:10px; padding:4px; border:1px solid #888; width:350px; }

            .sample h3 { margin:-4px; margin-bottom:10px; padding:4px; background:#555; color:#eee; }

            .currencyLabel { display:block; }        
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Sample 1
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#currencyButton').click(function()
                {
                    $('#currencyField').formatCurrency();
                    $('#currencyField').formatCurrency('.currencyLabel');
                });
            });

            // Sample 2
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('.currency').blur(function()
                {
                    $('.currency').formatCurrency();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="formPage">
            <h1>Format Currency Sample</h1>

            <div class="sample">
                <h3>Formatting Using Button Click</h3>
                <input type="textbox" id="currencyField" value="$1,220.00" />
                <input type="button" id="currencyButton" value="Convert" />

                <div>
                    Formatting Currency to an Html Span tag.
                    <span class="currencyLabel">$1,220.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sample">
                <h3>Formatting Using Blur (Lost Focus)</h3>

                <input type="textbox" id="currencyField" class='currency' value="$1,220.00" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please refer :

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

Demo fiddle: jsfiddle.net/2wEe6/72

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now, That is example of converting, where I am looking for formatting as a client typing numbers in..

Comment: You can use the onchange event when user type it will get changed.Here is an demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2wEe6/72/. Use input change event for your goal.