# Output numbers with comma after 3 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have used this jQuery code

```
jQuery.fn.digits = function(){ 
    return this.each(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
    })
}
```

for number 150000
and i want it to out put like 150,000

but it is outputting this : 150,000.00

i don't want these extra .00

Comment: So what have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: Actually i don't understand the regex that why here to get some help.

Comment: Try this http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: So for what kind of numbers should this work? Just 150000 or any?

Comment: this will be any number 150000 is just for example.

Comment: It should be working. Are you sure that the $(this).text() returns "150000"? You can see it working there: https://regex101.com/r/wO8cB4/1

Comment: I would suggest looking the used signs up since this is a very easy regex. [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) page explains it well.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would add `.00` to your number. Are you sure the original is `150000` and not `150000.00`?

Comment: Also your regex is very simple: "A digit, which is followed by a multiple of 3 digits, with no further digits beyond."

Comment: Your code works for me. `.00` is only in the result if it's also in the input. See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7srLktto/2/

Comment: Take a look at my [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966148/how-can-i-format-currency-by-using-jquery/23966200), you should be able to use this little function to handle what you need with a few tweaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a `for` loop is easier to understand than a regex.

```
function addCommas(num) {
    var characters = parseInt(num, 10).toString();
    var output = '';
    for (var offset = characters.length; offset > 0; offset -= 3) {
        output = characters.slice(Math.max(offset - 3, 0), offset) + (output ? ',' + output : '');
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, edited to include a radix. Also note that this will round the input number to an integer, losing any digits after the decimal point. It's an easy exercise to capture those and append them back at the end, if needed.

Comment: The code in the question only outputs digits after the decimal if they're in the input. That seems to be what the OP is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery Number Formatter plugin, so you do not have to deal with such regular expressions to format your number:

[Jquery Number Formatter](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/)

Another work around would be to just trim the last 3 characters with

```
$(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,").slice(0,-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Math.round before your regex then substring after - this is untested

```
var newnumber = Math.round(parseInt($(this).text());
var withcommas = newnumber.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
$(this).text(withcommas.substring(0, s.indexOf('.')));
```